# DESTROY and undef?

Tags: perl, memory-management

I am writing a script to destroy or free memory for variables and object

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Mem;
sub new{
   my ($class,$args)=@_;
   my $self={};
   bless($self,$class);
   $self->{first}=$args->{first};
   print "In new \n";
   print "Values : ".$self->{first};

   return $self;
}
sub DESTROY{
   my $self=shift;
   print "In DESTROY \n";
   #undef $self;
   print "Values : ".$self->{first};
}

package main;

my $m=new Mem({first=> '2'});
```

If I don't use undef statement in DESTROY, I still get values. How do you use DESTROY and undef? And when do you use which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a DESTROY procedure only when you want to take some explicit action when an object is destroyed. A common use would be to ensure that open files have been closed. At the point DESTROY is called the object still exists, so that you can reference its contents, but it is in the process of being cleaned up by the system.

In your example, `$self->{first}` will still have a value in DESTROY, because the object still exists. When you use `undef` within the procedure you will completely wipe it out.

Using `undef` on a variable will be one of the things that could cause an object to be eligible to be destroyed (if it contains the last reference to the object). This will result in the DESTROY procedure being called, if one has been defined.

Comment: So I should use DESTROY only to clear or do necessary cleanup (like filehandle closing etc), And If I want to free memory, I should use `undef`. right?

Comment: Only define DESTROY if you need to do special clean-up. Setting something to `undef` will free the memory (or it will also get freed automatically when there are no more references to the object).

Answer (score 1):

That is because when control is in **DESTROY**, object tear-down is happening and it isn't over until control reaches end of **DESTROY**

If you access object after explicitly destroying it, then it will be clear. Mind you the print after *undef $m* is undefined.

```
package Mem;
sub new{
   my ($class,$args)=@_;
   my $self={};
   bless($self,$class);
   $self->{first}=$args->{first};
   print "In new \n";
   print "Values : ".$self->{first};

   return $self;
}
sub DESTROY{
   my $self=shift;
   print "In DESTROY \n";
   #undef $self;
   print "Values : ".$self->{first};
}

package main;

my $m=new Mem({first=> '2'});

undef $m;
print "in package main" , $m->{'first'}, "\n";
```

Comment: In your case,even if I don't use DESTROY, then also it gives no value for "in package main". So what is the point of using DESTROY then? Also I read that DESTROY is called automatically. So why do we need to use undef? Shouldn't this be done automatically?

Comment: **DESTROY** is a special routine which automatically called when object goes out of scope, in classical OOP term *destructor*. One can manually invoke **DESTROY** or **destructor** on an object via *undef*. I was saying that you can't access **$m->{'first'}** once **DESTROY** returns though no undef in **DESTORY**.